# Facebook LikeView change button size

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am using a LikeView in my android application and want to change the button size. Changing the view's size using layout parameters or the width/height at addView() does not help.

I'm using libGDX and have never worked with XML + libGDX, so a way to do it with code only would be nice!

Does anyone know how to do this? Currently I use the following code to create my LikeView:

```
likeButton = new LikeView(application);
likeButton.setLikeViewStyle(LikeView.Style.BUTTON);
likeButton.setX(x);
likeButton.setY(y); 

likeButton.setObjectId(LIKE_URL);
likeButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
application.layout.addView(likeButton,width,height);
likeButton.invalidate();
```

application.layout is a RelativeLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed it using setScale on the view. It's not the most elegant solution, but it does the job.

```
likeButton.setScaleX(1.8f);
likeButton.setScaleY(1.8f);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to create your LikeView from XML (or inflate this layout at runtime):

```
<com.facebook.widget.LikeView
    android:id="@+id/button_like"
    android:layout_height="31dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: I should have specified I'm using libGDX and it would probably be much easier if there is a way to do it with code. I have never worked with XML on android yet and having to find out how to integrate it with libGDX would take some time